# Wilson's theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Can you hint me on how to show that $2(p-3)!\equiv -1\pmod{p}$, for $p>2$ prime.

I that Wilson's theorem says that $(p-1)!\equiv-1\pmod{p}$, and that $(p-3)!=(p-3)(p-2)(p-1)!$, but I'm not seeing how to fit this together.

Comment: Certainly not true that $(p-3)!=(p-3)(p-2)(p-1)!$. You mean $(p-1)!=(p-1)(p-2)(p-3)!$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

$$(p-2)(p-1)=2\pmod p\;\;$$

Comment: Could you please explain how can you say that?

Comment: You know some modulo arithmetic? Well $$(p-2)(p-1)=p^2-3p+2=2\pmod p...$$ Or simpler: $\,(p-2)(p-1)=(-2)(-1)\pmod p=2\pmod p\,$ .