# A question of divisibility. (NBHM 2012)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The number $18! + 1$ is divisible by 437. How to prove it?

I have $(19-1)! + 1 \equiv 0$ (mod 19) and $437 = 19 \times 23$. What to do next?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $$(23-1)!\equiv-1\pmod{23}$$

Now, $\displaystyle 22!= (22\cdot21\cdot20\cdot19)\cdot18!\equiv(-1)(-2)(-3)(-4)\cdot18!\pmod{23}$

and $\displaystyle(-1)(-2)(-3)(-4)\equiv?\pmod{23}$

and use $(19,23)=1$

Comment: $(-1)(-2)(-3)(-4) \equiv 1$ (mod 23). So $18! \equiv 1$ (mod 23). We have $18! \equiv 1$ (mod 19). As $(19 , 23) = 1$, $[19, 23] = 19 \times 23 = 437$. Thus $18! + 1 \equiv 0$ (mod 437) i.e. $18! + 1$ is divisible by 437. Thank you.

Comment: @HopelessFool, my pleasure

Comment: @HopelessFool, why such weird ID:). Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282104/wilsons-theorem  and  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535233/wilsons-theorem-question